# Seekbar is not respont

Tags: android

I make a radio player and the seekbar is not turn up or down the volume and I can't find why happen this.

```
final SeekBar volume=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.bar);
audMan = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = audMan.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int curVolume = audMan.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mplayer = new MediaPlayer();
mplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

volume.setMax(maxVolume);
volume.setProgress(curVolume);
song_title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
seekBarValue=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Value=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekbarvalue);

song_title.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
seekBarValue.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
Value.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);

volume.setProgress(0);
volume.incrementProgressBy(5);
volume.setMax(100);

volume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar)
    {
        int value = bar.getProgress(); // the value of the seekBar progress
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar)
    {

    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar,
            int paramInt, boolean paramBoolean)
    {
        seekBarValue.setText("" + paramInt + "%"); // here in textView the percent will be shown
    }
});
```

Comment: is there any error occurs

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the [AudioManger.setStreamVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) at some point...

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar,
                int paramInt, boolean paramBoolean)
        {
            seekBarValue.setText("" + paramInt + "%"); // here in textView the percent will be shown
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,paramInt,flags);
        }
```

`flags` are just the flags to use. For instance `AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI` can be used to display a Toast with the volume. You can pass 0 if you don't want flags.

Comment: At AudioManager audioManager... is an error tells Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to AudioManager
and the flag is a varieble?